# Volley upload image using PHP

Tags: php, android, android-volley

I am trying to upload image from android app using Google Volley to the server but for some reason the SQL command to insert the URL to database and upload doesn't work. The rest of the commands as well as the code in android seems to be working. But the response is incorrect. Check the else statement below highlighted by comment, that statement is executed for some reason whatever I do.

```
<?php

 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){

 $image = $_POST['image'];
 $name = $_POST['name'];
 ... 
 $conn = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB) or die('unable to connect to db');


 $sql ="SELECT id FROM volleyupload ORDER BY id ASC";

 $res = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

  $id = 0;

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
    $id = $row['id'];
  }

  $path = "uploads/$id.png";

   $actualpath = "http://myurl.co/prak/$path";

   $sql = "INSERT INTO volleyupload (photo,name) VALUES ('$actualpath','$name')";

   if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
      file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
      echo "Successfully Uploaded";
   } else{
       echo "ERROR in insertion to DB!"; //THIS ERROR COMES UP
     }

   mysqli_close($conn);
 }else{
 echo "Error";
  }

 ?>
```

The tutorial I am following for volley image upload is here: https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-upload-image-to-server/

Please let me know what's the problem and if there is an issue with the question do let me know that as well.

Comment: Is Android part working without error messages? Image upload working fine, db writing also, but Android app throw error during uploading.

Comment: @KovacsAkos Sorry for a late reply but yes android part is working fine in case its useful. Thanks!

Comment: Could you please give me an example? Volley working really strange, it sometimes duplicate entries, do not show items...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fact that `else` branch is always entered means that `mysqli_query($conn,$sql)` function result is FALSE.

This is most likely caused by problem with your SQL statement. Fortunately there is a way to find out where exactly the problem origins - you can use `mysqli_error($conn)` to find out where the issue is exactly.

Possibly by adjusting your code to something like this:

```
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$sql)){
      file_put_contents($path,base64_decode($image));
      echo "Successfully Uploaded";
   } else{
       echo "ERROR in insertion to DB:" . mysqli_error($conn); //THIS ERROR COMES UP
     }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton bro. I found out that the error was in wrong column name which I used in PHP code. I had been trying for the past 5 hours. Thanks a lot.